# ClamTK Anti Virus will not run on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: security, malware, antivirus, clamav, clamtk

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 15.10.

To protect myself, I have tried downloading and installing ClamTK. It does this without giving any error messages but it doesn't open.

I tried on a second Ubuntu 15.10 laptop and it wouldn't install either. Can this be fixed?

Comment: "To protect myself," against what? If -not- windows virusses ... forget about ClamTK. Up to today it is a waste of resources, there is not  a single virus loose that targets linux systems (yet). And if you stick to software from USC and use websites you -can- trust you are only wasting resources.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Didn't you hear about that latest Linux ransomware? And you know that most viruses are cross-platform now and don't necessarily even care what OS they run on. I found ClamAV very useful for getting rid of phishing scripts which are not OS-specific but instead browser-specific so it is still useful.

Comment: When you say it wouldn't install, what exactly do you mean? If there is an error message given please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: How exactly did you try to install it? Did you download the official `.deb` installation file from their site, or did you go to the Ubuntu Software Center, or...?

Comment: @user468313 No, a virus written for Windows will not run on Linux. sure, there are Linux viruses... But the fact that they make the news shows how rare they are...

Answer (score 3):

You may have more luck with [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/ubuntu/clamtk). Simpy use these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:landronimirc/clamtk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clamtk
```

Or there is the alternative [ClamXAV](https://www.clamxav.com/).